# search through web-service with json

Tags: android, json, web-services

In my android application i`m using web-service to get information about food the problem that if i write appl instead of apple,row,skin it dosen`t fill automatically and an error message will be shown,, what i did i stored 2000 name from web service in sqlite and search through them is it wrong to do this ? and how can i search with misspelling in web-service without the error message ?
The api url http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=apple&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: what adapter are you using? post its code

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myData);
 autoCom.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)

Comment: sorry, but i didn`t get that, if i search like this http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=app&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=DEMO_KEY                  there will be an error message so what is constraints ?

Comment: then check inside `runQuery` if the root element is "list" or "errors"

Comment: So it depends on the api and this api doesn`t allow searching with one letter ?

Comment: yes,  it seems so

Comment: thanks for help but is it ok to save it on sqlite ?

Answer (score 0):

Salam Enas,
If the data  do change frequently (like a movies list) then it's **not** ok to store it in the sqlite and it's better to be stored in the server database.
If the data does not change frequently, then it's ok to store them on the sqlite database although the app size will increase by 2 Mb which is a drawback.
You may also want to consider other APIs if you are not committed to use this one.
When storing data on the server, HTTP requests burden can be alleviated by caching data on the mobile.
good luck :)